# Rate Limit Exception in Twitter Search API

Tags: twitter

I am getting rate limit exception while fetching data from twitter. I am using twitter search Api. 
The code was running perfectly till 1.5 month. Suddenly it stopped giving rate limit exception.
As per my knowledge, Rate limits in version 1.1 of the API are divided into 15 minute intervals.
Please let me know what is the exact rate limit and how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting and https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits

The rate limit for Search API in v1.1 is 180(user auth) and 450(app auth) per 15 minutes window. 
You need to code accordingly.